# Is it possible to connect via mongo shell in read-only mode?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Is there any way to connect to MongoDB using mongo shell with read-only mode?

> $ mongo "mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017/?**readOnly=true**"

I know I can create read only user then connect to DB.

Comment: You can try invoking `mongo` shell with _access control_ (related to [Security](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/security/index.html)), so that you can have certain resources protected with proper access.

Comment: Thank you @prasad_. I'll check that. I was just looking a simple approach just by enabling read-only mode from shell client.

Comment: Security doesn't control the tool. But, it gives means to control access to the data.

Comment: Above response of @prasad_ was on my this comment which I deleted as I was not able edit.  "I could not achieve with  [Security](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/security/) as prasad_ suggested."